# Return the view with the css class in the controller of asp.net mvc c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I used to put the class of css in the action link like this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Us", "Us", "Por", new { @class = "contactus" })%>
```

The purpose that I put the class is for the pop up of color box.
Now I have an action in my controller that return the result to the view like this :

```
return Redirect(@"~/Test/TestFirst?msg=Please complete all the information.");
```

Question : How can I add class = "contactus" to the return of my action ?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Controller cannot and should not add css classes, this is the views responsibility. And it looks like you are stuffing a message in the query string, but it probably should be in the TempData

Controller:

```
TempData["msg"] = "Please complete all the information";
return Redirect(@"~/Test/TestFirst");
```

View:

```
@if(TempData["msg"] != null)
{
  <div class="myclass">@TempData["msg"]</div>
}
```

notice that TempData will survive a redirect.

Comment: Thanks. But are there any solution to add the class to my link beside this?

Comment: @titi not from the controller

Comment: Thanks. But why don't you tell me the solution?

Comment: @titi I added some more details .. let me know if you need more help

Comment: @BassamMehanni +1 for pointing out that the view is responsible for rendering the page (client-side representation); separation of concerns is the whole point of the MVC paradigm